# How to avoid Coloring the Full Table \Cellcolor

Tags: tables, color

I have tried \cellcolor, \rowcolor ... but this always result in coloring the full table. Given my table implementation how can I color a cell? Thanks

```
\documentclass[annual]{acmsiggraph}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\title{Dice Probability}
\author{Xavier Dupont\thanks{e-mail: email@hotmail.com}}
\pdfauthor{Xavier Dupont}
\keywords{Dice, Probability}


\newcommand\ML[1]{\llap{#1\quad}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{TAB}(e,1cm,1cm){ccccccc}{ccccccc}   
        Dice {\color{blue}$B$} 
\end{TAB}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
\begin{TAB}(e,1cm,1cm){|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}   
\ML{}   \textbf{\LARGE +}     & {\color{blue}0}    & {\color{blue}1}    & {\color{blue}2}    & {\color{blue}3}   & {\color{blue}4}    & {\color{blue}5}\\
\ML{}   {\color{red}1}    & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\ML{}   {\color{red}2}    & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\ML{}   {\color{red}3}    & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\ML{}   {\color{red}4}    & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\ML{}   {\color{red}5}    & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\ML{}   {\color{red}6}    & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & \cellcolor{red!50}{12} \\
\end{TAB}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about you give is more complete example that shows the definition of your `TAB` environment? Can you do that?

Comment: Yes - TAB environment comes from \usepackage[thinlines]{easytable} - I need square table - thanks

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459690/color-fraction-of-table-cell/459717#459717 (but not a duplicate)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What Werner means is instead of posting code fragmets can you please post a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This is a minimal piece of code that compiles and demonstrates your problem. It is *much* easier to help you if you give us working code to start from.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Werner - updated minimal working environment

Comment: @Xavier If this is your real email address, you might want to remove it unless you have a very good spam filter

Comment: @Xavier: Where would we find `acmsiggraph.cls`?

Comment: @Werner https://github.com/markkilgard/avgrutghp/blob/master/acmsiggraph.cls

Comment: @Xavier: Your code provides [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAiCg.png) as output, where the blue/red colour stays within each cell. So, I can't replicate your behaviour - "...this always result[s] in coloring the full table."

Comment: @Werner - I have added a example of this abnormal color behavior \cellcolor

Answer (score 2):

I hope this construction works for you, for some reason I could not run your example, my package manager did not recognize `acmsiggraph` and did not install it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{colortbl} %color de tabla
\usepackage{setspace} %espacio en tablas
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}\begin{spacing}{1.3}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c| >{\columncolor{yellow!50}[1.0\tabcolsep]} c|c| c|}
            \hline 
            A & B & C & D & E & Total \\
            \hline 
            F & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 10 \\ 
            \hline 
            \rowcolor{green!50}[1.0\tabcolsep]
            G &  &  & $s$ &  & $n$ \\
            \hline  
            H &  &  &  &  &   \\
            \hline 
            Total &  &  & $m$ &  &  \cellcolor{red!50} $t$ \\
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}  \\
    \end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]